# Cascade trigger field validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with two numeric input, let say input1 and input2.

I would like to have the following validation rules:

- R1: input2 <= input1 * 0.2 (triggered when input1 or input2 values change)
- R2: input1 <10

Forget for a moment R2 and look at this code:

```
<input id="input1" class="validation1"/>
<input id="input2" class="validation2"/>

$.validator.addMethod("validation2", function (value, element) {
  var v = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
  var l = Globalize.parseFloat($('#input1').val());
  return !l || !v || v <= l*0.2;
}, "Error");
$.validator.classRuleSettings.validation2= { validation2: true };

$.validator.addMethod("validation1", function (value, element) {
  var validator = $("form").validate();
  validator.element($('#input2'));
  return true;
}, "should never be shown");
$.validator.classRuleSettings.validation1= { validation1: true };
```

This code works pretty well.
Validation of input2 is called when input1 or input2 change.

So let's add R2 by editing validation1 in this way:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validation1", function (value, element) {
  var validator = $("form").validate();
  validator.element($('#input2'));

  var v = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
  return v && v<10;
}, "Input1 must be less than 10");
```

This code works as expected but once that input1 is set greater than 10 it became red and it remains red also when value is changed to be <10.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get your code to function in a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/TcpnH/

Perhaps you can construct a jsFiddle.

**Some notes:**

---

**1)**  IMPORTANT:  All inputs **must** contain a `name` attribute or this plugin will not operate as intended.  Even if you don't use that `name` for anything else in your jQuery, it's still required.

```
<input id="input1" name="input1" class="validation1" />
```

---

**2)**  If `input1` must simply be less than 10, why are you creating a whole new method for that?  Simply use the built-in `max` method/rule.  `max: 10`

---

**3)**  `$.validator.classRuleSettings.validation1= { validation1: true };`  I don't see `classRuleSettings` anyplace in [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), nor do I see the purpose.

Typically a custom method/rule would be added as a `class` on the element, which you've already done:

```
<input id="input1" class="validation1" />
```

Otherwise, declared as a rule:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        myfieldname: {
            validation1: true
        }
    }
});
```